# How to get instance URL using OAuth?

Tags: api, url, oauth, instance

Is there a way to get the user instance URL using the API? Or any other way? I am using OAuth to get the user token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a variable in the returned JSON which gives the instance URL.

`instance_url`

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_iot.meta/api_iot/qs_auth_access_token.htm